# How to find the bounds of the marginal pdf given joint density bounds?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, density-function

I am provided the following joint density:

$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y)~=~\begin{cases}
\lambda^3xe^{-\lambda y} & 0\le x \le y\\
\end{cases}
$$

I am supposed to be able to find the density of $Y$ and $E(Y)$. Note that $\lambda$ is just a constant.

I have calculated the density of $Y$ as:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
f_Y(y) &= \int_0^y\lambda^3xe^{-\lambda y}dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\lambda^3y^2e^{-\lambda y}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

But I do not know what my bounds are on $f_Y(y)$. Would it be $x<y<\infty$ since $y$ is unbound in the positive direction in the joint density?

If so, then is the expectation of Y below correct?

$$
E(Y) = \int^{\infty}_0yf_Y(y)dy
$$

Comment: The bounds on $y$ are zero and $\infty$. Integrate the density to check that this integral is one.

Comment: Once you marginalize over $x$ your bounds on $y$ are $0\leq y < \infty$

Comment: And what you wrote in the end is $E(Y)$ i.e. the expected value of $Y$, not $X$.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right, I've edited it accordingly. Also, thank you both for confirming!